# Importing/Reading parameters in Ruby Test Unit

Tags: ruby, testing, csv, selenium, webdriver

Please please help me before I lose it!

I'm using Ruby Test Unit and Selenium Webdriver. All of my tests start with a login function, therefore I want the tests to pull the username and password values from a central script/csv/text file, whatever is easiest. This would make it easier to control login details from one place rather than hard coding them into every script. I am not a Ruby programmer and therefore I am not finding this particularly easy. I'm thinking I should be able to declare the username and password parameters in the 'def setup' section, so that it reads the values from an external source.

Is this possible?

```
   require "selenium-webdriver"
   require "test/unit"


   class CMSNewslist < Test::Unit::TestCase

      def setup
       @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
       @base_url = "http://skyintranet/"
       @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 90
       @verification_errors = []
      end

      def teardown
       @driver.quit
       assert_equal [], @verification_errors
      end


      def test_c_m_s_newslist
       @driver.get(@base_url + "/Enterprise-Applications-Test/")
       @driver.find_element(:link, "Login").click
       @driver.find_element(:id,     "ctl00_MainRegion_LoginView_LoginControl_UserName").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_MainRegion_LoginView_LoginControl_UserName").send_keys  "Ruband"
@driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_MainRegion_LoginView_LoginControl_Password").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_MainRegion_LoginView_LoginControl_Password").send_keys  "Donn1982"
@driver.find_element(:id, "ctl00_MainRegion_LoginView_LoginControl_LoginBtn").click
assert_equal "Logout", @driver.find_element(:class, "loginButton").text, "Login Unsuccessful"
puts "Login Successful"
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in a separate file and read it or have a mixin that gets included in each script.

```
module LoginConfig
    @@username = 'foo'
    @@password = 'bar'
end
```

Then within your class CMSNewslist:

```
...
require 'login_config'

class CMSNewslist < Test::Unit::TestCase
    include LoginConfig
...
```

Then you can use @@username and @@password.  Here's a decent tutorial on Mixins...
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm